# Aurelia route matching

Tags: routes, aurelia

**NOTE: pushState is enabled**

I have an issue / question related to aurelia route matching. I have the following routes in the **app.ts**:

```
{
  route: ['profile'],
  href: '#',
  name: 'profile',
  moduleId: PLATFORM.moduleName('../pages/profile', 'profile'),
  title: 'Profile'
},
{
  route: [':continents/:countries'],
  name: 'countries',
  moduleId: PLATFORM.moduleName('../pages/countries', 'countries'),
  title: 'Countries'
}
```

In the **profile.ts** module, I do another configRoute, where I set another 2 child routes, like:

```
{
  route: ['personal'],
  href: '#',
  name: 'personal',
  moduleId: PLATFORM.moduleName('./personal', 'personal'),
  title: 'Personal'
},
{
  route: ['skills'],
  href: '#',
  name: 'skills',
  moduleId: PLATFORM.moduleName('./skills', 'skills'),
  title: 'Skills'
}
```

The problem is the following: when I navigate to `/profile/skills` or `/profile/personal`, the route will match the countries one (`':continents/:countries'`). Which I think makes sense because the whole segment matches that.

I could change the profile route to

```
{
  route: ['profile', 'profile/:tabName'],
  href: '#',
  name: 'profile',
  moduleId: PLATFORM.moduleName('../pages/profile', 'profile'),
  title: 'Profile'
},
```

but then my routes would be like `/profile/personal/personal` or `/profile/personal/skills` which I don't want.

I've tried to add the wildcard symbol as suggested in the aurelia docs:

```
{
  route: ['profile', 'profile/*tabName'],
  href: '#',
  name: 'profile',
  moduleId: PLATFORM.moduleName('../pages/profile', 'profile'),
  title: 'Profile'
},
```

but a route like `/profile/skills` did not match it and it still went to the `':continents/:countries'`.

Can I somehow force it to go to the `profile` page? (apart from child-routing `'countries'`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main application router gets first dibs on trying to match a route string, and `profile/skills` matches  `':continents/:countries'`.

`':continents/:countries'` is the equivalent of `.+/.+` as a route regex. It matches pretty much any string with a slash in the middle of it.

You need to add something like `'earth/:continents/:countries'` to that route. Adding some hardcoded string to the beginning of it makes it stop being so all-encompassing.

Comment: Yeah, that's my last resort for now :). Thank you for your input. How come though that making it parametrized ('profile/:tabName') made it intercept the intended route (profile, although with a messed up url) and the wildcard didn't?

Comment: B/c if you tell the router to look for a parameter, then it looks for `profile/.+`

Comment: End result is that the `:foo/:bar` style of route isn't going to work for you in your root router.

Comment: I see, so my only two options is adding the static prefix `'earth'` in front of it or make the `:countries` part a child route of the `:continents`..

Comment: You have to give the router something to match against. The router is "greedy" and will match stuff if it can, it doesn't ask child routers if they can match a route before matching as that would cause serious perf issues. You've given the router a route that matches pretty much anything that has a slash in it, so it's gonna suck up everything it can.